# top domain .world not working in java struts 2 app

Tags: java, struts2, web.xml

I have pointed my domain analytix.world to my java struts 2 web application, 
The pointing is absolutely correct, as I have tested with a test.php web page. but when I am trying to open struts action it is saying 404

What I believe is that web.xml or struts Dispatcher is invalidating analytix.world as a non valid url and thus not pointing to the action required

Please Suggest

Comment: Why do you believe that?

Comment: Because my other domain are able to hit successfully to actions, they are all .com domains, also when I validated the analytix.world domain online , it is pointing it as a non valid . So I think may be some place inside java libraries of tomcat or might be filter, it also checks the validity of the url and then accordingly take it forward

Comment: http://sqa.fyicenter.com/1000207_Domain_Name_Validator.html#Result : This website is classfying it as invalid top domain url (.world)

Comment: That website is just wrong, that has nothing to do with you. Are there any errors in your logs?